# Any hints on how to train a nn dependency parser on a new corpus?

Tags: stanford-nlp

We'd like to train the Stanford NN dependency parser on a Russian corpus, are there any hints on how to do it? The hyper-parameters are described in the paper, however it would be nice to understand how to prepare the training data (Annotations, and specifically how to create word2vec annotations). Any help or a reference to some document is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some answers:

- the site for word2vec if you want to build vector representations for Russian:

  https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/
- the dependencies need to be in the CoNLL-X format:

  http://ilk.uvt.nl/conll/#dataformat

  The word embeddings should be in this format (each word vector on its own line):

  WORD\tn0 n1 n2 n3 n4 ...

  for instance:

  apple    .45242 .392323 .111423 .999334

  put your embeddings in a file called russian_embeddings.txt
- the training command (assumes your word vectors have dimension=50)

  ```
  java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -tlp edu.stanford.nlp.trees.international.RussianTreebankLanguagePack -trainFile russian/train.conll -devFile russian/dev.conll -embedFile russian_embeddings.txt -embeddingSize 50 -model nndep.russian.model.txt.gz
  ```
- A big complication is that as of the moment, edu.stanford.nlp.trees.international.RussianTreebankLanguagePack does not exist, so you will have to create this class and model it after the TreebankLanguagePacks for other languages ; if you look around in the package edu.stanford.nlp.trees.international , you can see what these TreebankLanguagePack files look like for other languages (note: the French one is only 143 lines long, so making a similar class for Russian is not out of the question at all) ; I will consult with other group members and see if I can get some clarity on what you'd have to do to complete this task
- There are a lot of challenges to building this Russian NN dependency parse model.  If you would like more help please let me know.  I will talk to the developers of the NN parser and see if I can give you more advice, these answers are meant as a starting point!

Comment: Thanks! We've started on this challenge, your comments are very helpful! We'll definitely let you know if we get stuck, or if we succeed!

Comment: Hi! We've stacked on building of RussianTreebankLanguagePack. All language packs use a lot of dependencies such as HeadFinder, Lexer and so on. So, it looks like the building of TreebankLanguagePack is really tricky task.
I'd like to know what is the purpose of TreebankLanguagePack? Is it really required for building NN dependency parser model for any language?
In article *A Fast and Accurate Dependency Parser using Neural Networks* authors train model without any special rules for english and chinese grammar.

Comment: We figured out what non-projective dependencies are and we talked to the corpus authors. Seems like 10% of their examples are non-projective, and its a feature for them, not a bug. They claim that transforming such trees into non-projective dependencies is a very bad idea. I'm wondering whether you had a similar problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: I will get some more specific answers, but I know that the dependency parser doesn't use the TreebankLanguagePack very much (or at all).  I will consult with some group members, but I am confident we can come up with a small implementation that will allow you to continue.

Comment: We managed to get good results, training on the Russian corpus, but now we'd like to be able to make a pipeline that parses russian sentences. We have some C components in the pipeline (the lemmatizer and POS tagger). So this will probably be much dirtier than the usual Standford NLP pipelines, but we're not sure how to get that to work. Right now if we try to use the parser, the English POS tagger is fetched.

Comment: We also managed to build russian language model for Stanford POS tagger, but it's still not clear how to substitute our _russian.lang.tagger_ instead default _english-left3words-distsim.tagger_ . How can we do this?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025113/treebanklanguagepack-function-in-neural-network-dependency-parser

Comment: Existing implementation for RussianTreebankLanguagePack: https://github.com/MANASLU8/CoreNLP